# How to get position of inserted item using DiffUtil?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been stuck on a rather simple problem for some time now. And for some reason, I'm not able to find StackOverflow answers on this so I thought I'd ask directly for help.

The problem is simple, I have a list of Transaction objects that are sorted by date. I'm adding a new Transaction to the list and then resorting it. Since I don't know the position where the new Transaction was added, I'm trying to use `DiffUtil` to figure it out for me and update the `RecyclerView` contents appropriately.

However, the result I'm getting is really odd. For some reason, the entire list is updating and the order is getting completely messed up. The underlying data however, is correct.

Before updating list:
[image]

After updating list:
[image]
Here's the code I have in my `Adapter` for adding a new Transaction item.

```
void addItem(Transaction transaction) {
    ArrayList<Transaction> oldList = new ArrayList<>(transactions);
    transactions.add(transaction);
    Collections.sort(transactions);

    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffCallback(oldList, transactions), false);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

And finally, here's my `DiffUtilCallback` implementation

```
class DiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    private List<Transaction> oldList;
    private List<Transaction> newList;

    public DiffCallback(List<Transaction> oldList, List<Transaction> newList) {
        this.oldList = oldList;
        this.newList = newList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        Transaction oldItem = oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        Transaction newItem = newList.get(oldItemPosition);
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        Transaction oldItem = oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        Transaction newItem = newList.get(oldItemPosition);
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }
}
```

Here's the `Transaction` class

```
public class Transaction implements Comparable<Transaction> {

public String category;
public String description;
public Date date;
public Double amount;

public Transaction(String description, Date date, Double amount) {
    this.category = "";
    this.description = description;
    this.date = date;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Transaction(String category, String description, Date date, Double amount) {
    this.category = category;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = date;
    this.amount = amount;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Transaction transaction) {
    if (this.category.compareTo(transaction.category) == 0) {
        return this.date.compareTo(transaction.date);
    }
    return this.category.compareTo(transaction.category);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Transaction)) {
        return false;
    }

    Transaction other = (Transaction)obj;
    return this.category.equals(other.category)
        && this.description.equals(other.description)
        && this.date.equals(other.date)
        && this.amount.equals(other.amount);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciate. Please let me know if more information is required to clarify the problem.

Comment: post `Transaction` class

Comment: @KishoreJethava posted

Comment: You're first sorting by `Transaction.category` and then by `Transaction.date`. From screenshot I can seed that your transactions are sorted by `date` but in 2 different sets. I suspect your code is working correctly.

Comment: If you just want to sort by `date` remove the parts about `category` in `compareTo`.

Comment: @HamedMomeni Thanks for commenting. The `category` was added because this is part of a bigger application. But in the screenshots provided, all transactions were given the same category, so that's probably not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `areContentsTheSame` you should compare attributes of `Transaction` but you're comparing `Transaction` object itself.

updated `areContentsTheSame`

```
@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
    Transaction oldItem = oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
    Transaction newItem = newList.get(oldItemPosition);

    return oldItem.category == newItem.category  && oldItem.description== newItem.description && oldItem.date== newItem.date && oldItem.amount == newItem.amount;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I implemented the `equals` method inside `Transaction` to do that. Please see the `Transaction` code in my question.

Comment: `Comparable<Transaction>` is not required to implement in `Transaction`

Comment: I want to sort the transactions in order they occurred (by date) and category. That's why I'm implementing `Comparable`. You think that could be causing issues?

Comment: Ohh, I forgot that. Are you getting same problem?